# PostGIS: Describe bands in raster

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a raster loaded into PostGIS, but I do not know what bands it contains.  \d doesn't tell me.

How do I get a list of bands in the raster? (And anything else you feel I should know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either  [`ST_BandMetaData`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_BandMetaData.html) or [`ST_MetaData`](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MetaData.html) which will give back vital Raster info.